# Send text messages to iphone by email

Tags: messages, sms

I'm looking for a cheap hack to text myself alerts whenever my server is down. (I know there's services like Nagios etc, I don't want to get into that.) I'm already sending out emails, so I'm looking for a quick way to add my phone as another recipient to the list of emails.

I know individual carriers have different ways of doing this, but I'm looking for something apple-specific since all of the members on my team have iPhones but with different carriers.

Comment: There are dozens of apps that use APNS to push notifications. Did you ever find anything or should we tick the accepted for the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Try [**IFTTT**](https://ifttt.com/). This lets you set up recipes that can do things, such as send an SMS when an email is received. The contents of the SMS can be customised based on the contents of the email, such as including the subject and/or body of the email in the SMS.

[image]

<sup>The tag is customisable and optional.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

No answer in four years?  Only one of the first ten DuckDuckGo hits for `SMS by email` was a false hit.  The first was:

https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-send-a-text-from-your-email-account/

Seventh was a non-free service that does not require you to know the recipient's provider:

https://www.textmagic.com/email-to-sms/